# CSS with localization

Tags: asp.net, css, localization

Found these steps in a forum,

1-add App_GlobalResources folder

2-add  Resource.resx in above folder

3-add Cssurl and your string in above Resource.resx

simply change your href to this

```
<link href="<%$ Resources: Resource , Cssurl %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

though this isnt working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
    css.Href = "css/fancyforms.css";
    css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
    css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
    css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(css); 
}
```

giving css.href value in condition solved my problem :)